# Disable shell prompt in linux

Tags: linux, headless

I am using minimal linux without having any GUI installed. I am looking for a way to disable any shell prompt after the system boots but the services should normally start in the background. Either it should show any customised screen or just the black screen without any input terminal.

Does Linux provide any configuration or setting for that?

Comment: What, like tty9 (for example)?

Comment: Second thought. If you want nothing displayed, why not unplug the monitor?

Comment: Yes, removing the monitor completely would be easiest. Also, uninstalling all packages having to do with graphical user interfaces.

Comment: @roaima, it will still show some sort of input terminal. I don't want any user to run any command over it.

Comment: @Kusalananda, I already don't have GUI, but I also don't want anybody to use via CLI as well.

Comment: @ruhewo How can a monitor that has been removed still show a login prompt? If the issue is that you may have someone hook up a monitor to it, then don't add users with no passwords to the system. Note that you can't physical security without locking the machine in a safe and disconnecting the network cable. Else, anyone cold attach a keyboard and monitor to it and reboot it into single user mode.  It would be helpful if you could update your question with what you actual aim  is for this system.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at "man inittab"

The file /etc/inittab is consulted and defines the login servers that are started by init.

There you can also define what happens for CTR-ALT-DELETE and similar.

Comment: inittab doesnot allow booting with any shell prompt or input terminal